# Getting unsupported media type when trying to send a list of Strings with POST request

Tags: javascript, java, rest, maven, jax-rs

I am trying to send a list of strings with javascript to my java backend but I get unsupported media type response. I have something like this in my backend:

```
@Path("/myPath")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response myMethod(List<String> myList) {
   //do something
}
```

and my request looks something like this:

```
var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            data: ["a", "b"]
        }
```

If I use `String myList` instead of `List<String> myList` in the backend it works without a problem. I am using javax.ws.rs-api for my rest and I thought it can automatically convert a JSON string to a list, is that not the case?

Comment: You need to add a JSON Provider. You can use a String because pretty much any media type can be converted to String. The String provider is provided out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            data: JSON.stringify(["a", "b"])

        }
```

Comment: I did try that, it doesn't seem to be the problem.